# Can plain text be hidden/accessed in laptop Firmware? (or elsewhere, not HDD/SSD)

Tags: forensics, destruction, firmware

Scenario: I just took 1 page of text (.odt) and copied it into a plain text document, that happens to result in a 3KB file.

With that as a random size criteria for discussion, CAN code be written to hide that document in firmware such that it can be accessed, edited with a plain text editor, and then put back, as a means of bypassing traditional hard drive storage that can be confiscated and destroyed?

Comment: I am an embedded programmer. I could hide the entire bible outside the HDD if I had hardware access and motivation.

Comment: @medivh That should be fun. :P Go for it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very simple answer is yes, and you can check this for yourself by reading BIOS information, or the text that is stored in various devices and drivers. You could even store text in the firmware in most modern keyboards.

Next time you update your BIOS, look at the upgrade file in a hex editor - loads of text in there, comments fields etc.

Comment: I wasn't aware that modern keyboards even had user-accessible firmware (as opposed to flashed in an 8051 on the controller).

Comment: That is very true, forest...I was just keeping it simple and high level.